# Accessing self-referencing field in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have class `User`, with field `friends`

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

when I migrated class to database, it created two tables. `app_user` and `app_user_friends`

`app_user` in itself has no reference to friends, but `app_user_friends` has `id` of a user, and `id` of a friend.

The issue is: qhen I try to access friends of a user by calling

```
      user = models.User.objects.get(id=user_id)
      print(user.friends)
```

I get

```
      app.User.None
```

Should I be calling it differently or is there something wrong with the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be calling it differently or is there something wrong with the model?

There is **nothing wrong** with your model. `user.friends` is just a `RelatedManager`. In order to retrieve all the friends, you need to add `.all()` (just like you need to add that for `User.objects` for example):

```
print(user.friends.all())
```

Note that by default `ManyToManyField`s to the same model are *symmetric*. This means that if *a* is a friend of *b*, then *b* is a friend of *a* as well. This is not *wrong*. For more information, look at the [**`symmetrical=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical).

Comment: Ohhh! Thank you so much!